# some View Make ViewPager UnSwipeAble

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, swipe

As You can See at the Begin Have LinearLaout Contain TextView
And Two Button .
There Is Another LinearLaout Contain ListView But it is Gone

So I Click on Button To Show ListView Visle , but ListView Make ViewPage UnSwipleAble , Since Click On ListView Area For Swipe .

And When Back To ExLayout (LinearLayout That Contain TextView) Make ViewPage UnSwipeAble Too ! :D

What is The Reason ? How To Fix It ?

```
               if (lytDesc.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    lytLastList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    lytDesc.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btnSubmit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btnLast.setText(" بازگشت ");
                    makeListView();
                } else if (lytLastList.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    lytLastList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btnSubmit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    lytDesc.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btnLast.setText(" پیگیری وضعیت ");
                }
```

[image]

---

Answer (score 0):

:|

Problem Solve Just Remove This  From TextViews

```
  android:singleLine="true"
```